# Get bean id from class

Tags: java, spring

I have the following bean :

```
   <bean id="slpStore"
          class="com.strategy.interceptor.SlpStoreInterceptor" >
    </bean>
```

I suppose only one bean exists in the spring context from the SlpStoreInterceptor.class, How can I retrieve the id of this bean which is "slpStore" if I only know the class name :SlpStoreInterceptor.class?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType()` method:

```
@Component
public class BeanNames {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public BeanNames(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public String[] getBeanNames() {
        return applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(SlpStoreInterceptor.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Michael I know but I was lazy... but if every code sample here uses setter injection this pattern will perpetuate forever. I've therefore changed the code to use constructor injection.

Comment: I figured that was probably the case. Shame because with Lombok the result can be equally terse: 1 annotation, just on the class, not the field. But it would make the example less clear. This could be a record (though loses encapsulation) but maybe it's a bit premature to be using them in examples. Anyway, thanks for improving it!